# How to make parameter of function is a "generic" struct

Tags: go, struct

For example, I want to write a method like this:

```
func parseData(rawData []json.RawMessage) []interface{} {
    var migrations []interface{}
    for _, migration := range rawData {
        // this is an custom struct
        command := UserCommand{}
        json.Unmarshal(migration, &command)
        migrations = append(migrations, command)
    }

    return migrations
}
```

The problem of this code is: If I don't want to parse `UserCommand` but any other such as `ProductCommand`, I must write the same code, only different at line: `command := UserCommand{}`. So my question is: how can I generic this code.

I have tried this solution but it doesn't work:

```
func parseData(rawData []json.RawMessage, class interface{}) []interface{} {
    var migrations []interface{}
    for _, migration := range rawData {
        command := class
        json.Unmarshal(migration, &command)
        migrations = append(migrations, command)
    }

    return migrations
}
// then I call this method
parseData(data, UserCommand{})
```

But it doesn't work. It return array of `map[string]interface{}` How can I fix this.

Edit:

Here is some my defined struct

```
type UserCommand struct {
    User string
    Info string
}
type ProductCommand struct {
    Name      string
    Quanlity  int
}
```

Comment: Someone downvote. please explain for me why. Because I am a newbie of Go, and I have tried as many as solutions I can before asking this.

Comment: Can't speak for the initial votes, but I find the question unclear. What is `ProductCommand`? What is `class`? Why not unmarshal directly into `class` if that's what you want? The type you're unmarshaling into in the second example is `*interface{}`, so the documented default type that's used for the `interface{}` is `map[string]interface{}`.

Comment: @JimB I have added `UserCommand` and `ProductCommand` to my code. Thanks for your point. Because I am newbie of Go, so I just use all the ways around :( So as you pointed out, it really doesn't make sense. Can you do this in general way ?

Comment: @TrầnKimDự how do you decide which type to unmarshal into?

Comment: [one way](https://play.golang.org/p/8X5FB32kDKd) and [another way](https://play.golang.org/p/nkEFDsSNSXi)

Comment: @mkopriva I tried second solution. and then after finishing method, I try to typecast again to original command. i.e: `migration.(CreateUserCommand).UserName`. But I meet followed exception: "*main.UserCommand, not main.UserCommand"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> // I want to be able to call this method
> parseData(data, UserCommand{})
> ```

It is possible to support this style of "generic" signature by using Go's [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type UserCommand struct {
    User string
    Info string
}

type ProductCommand struct {
    Name     string
    Quantity int
}

func parseData(rawData []json.RawMessage, class interface{}) []interface{} {
    var parsed []interface{}
    for _, elem := range rawData {
        // Create a pointer to a new zero value of the same type as `class`.
        command := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(class))
        // Pass a pointer to the new value to `json.Unmarshal`.
        json.Unmarshal(elem, command.Interface())
        // Insert the pointed-to new value into the output slice.
        parsed = append(parsed, command.Elem().Interface())
    }
    return parsed
}

func main() {
    data := []json.RawMessage{
        json.RawMessage(`{"User":"u1","Info":"i1"}`),
        json.RawMessage(`{"User":"u2","Info":"i2"}`),
    }
    parsed := parseData(data, UserCommand{})
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", parsed)

    data = []json.RawMessage{
        json.RawMessage(`{"Name":"n1","Quantity":1}`),
        json.RawMessage(`{"Name":"n2","Quantity":2}`),
    }
    parsed = parseData(data, ProductCommand{})
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", parsed)
}
```

The output shows that the first `parseData` call has parsed two `UserCommand` structs and the second call has parsed two `ProductCommand` structs.

```
[]interface {}{main.UserCommand{User:"u1", Info:"i1"}, main.UserCommand{User:"u2", Info:"i2"}}
[]interface {}{main.ProductCommand{Name:"n1", Quantity:1}, main.ProductCommand{Name:"n2", Quantity:2}}
```